# Split string/variable on first occurrence delimiter (UNIX)

Tags: unix, scripting, ksh

I would like to split the string with delimiter. 
variable my_string contains Hello_This_Is_My_string
The output will be only

Below is my code :

```
result = $(echo $my_string |" cut -d '_' -f2")
```

However, I am getting `<Is>` instead of `<This_Is_My_string>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found an answer:

```
result=$(echo $my_string | cut -d "_" -f 2-)
```

Test with:

```
echo aa_bb_cc | cut -d "_" -f 2-
```

Comment: If it works and is the answer, mark it as answer. Others may find it useful.

Comment: I cant mark the answer as there is a prompt said "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Comment: I do not understand your quotes. Use `result=$(echo $my_string | cut -d "_" -f 2-)`.

Comment: @WalterA to cut the string with a delimiter "_"

Answer (score 2):

Avoid calling external commands, do it with shell-internal 'Parameter Expansion', which has quite powerfull options

```
my_string='Hello_This_Is_My_string'
echo "result = ${my_string#*_}"
```